# Is this possible to change port in RTSP using TCP?

Tags: tcp, rtsp, rtp, live555

I try to do this:
`Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;client_port=4578-4579;`
When I do that:
`Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=4578-4579;`
or that:
`Transport: RTP/AVP/TCP;unicast;interleaved=0-1;`
all works fine.
My question is: Is this possible to do first way? I wonder If it need to use 554 port only which I use to setup RTSP.

Comment: Isn't it the whole idea of TCP transport to use RTSP port to stream RTP data?

Comment: yes, but what if you need to use one more channel to transfer data to server?  audio + video server - client, audio + rtcp client - server

Comment: That's where interleaved option. is used. Check "10.12 Embedded (Interleaved) Binary Data" in [RFC2326](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use the first format. Of course, you should first have checked if both ports (TCP 4578 and TCP 4579) are in fact available on the client. If they're not, you can fall back to interleaved which does not require additional ports.

Note that you **don't** need port 554 on your side, that's the default server port for RTSP but you are looking from the client side.